# MATLAB settings - stop if errors

Tags: matlab, settings

I found the "always stop on error (dbstop if error)" to be very useful when I debug MATLAB code. 
However, closing matlab also resets it to "Never stop if error"

How can I make this setting persist?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the solution indeed - further digging in Mathworks brought up the exact details:

In the default folder typing

```
edit startup.m
```

And then writing

```
dbstop if error
```

Thanks Schroeder!

Comment: After using your answer, I see that the other settings are listed under the "Stop if Errors/Warnings..." dialog in parens next to the option selected (e.g., `dbstop if warning` for the equivalent warning option).  I.e., radio button, option, then command in parens.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You could use the *startup.m* file to recreate your settings at startup. See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/index.html?/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/startup.html) for more details.