# Debugging functions in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, debugging, visibility

**Question: Is there a preferred way to debug functions in matlab?**

If I all calculations in a script, then every variable is in the workspace and I can easily query them to find out what's not working right.  However, if I use a function, then only my outputs are visible and I can't see what's going wrong.  I understand there are ways of getting around this, but thusfar they seem to be more trouble than just making one, long ugly, script.  So how do YOU debug functions in matlab?  Is there a preferred/efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Did you even https://www.google.com/search?q=matlab+debug&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8? :)

Comment: Uh yeah, thanks the suggestion though

Comment: I mean, is there anyway to get variables without using the debugger?

Comment: The preferred/efficient way is to [use the debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html)...

Comment: damn!  i was hoping this wasn't the answer... thanks gang.

Comment: `dbstop if error` is always my first stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always make sure to enable ["Stop If Error"](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html#buzezti-1) in the Breakpoints menu and if I want to debug a specific function I set a breakpoint at the first line in that function (or at the point of interest). Note that "clear all", which is common in the beginning of scripts deletes all break points. Use "clear variables" instead.

See [MATLAB settings - stop if errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396449/matlab-settings-stop-if-errors) for more info on how to make the Stop If Error persist when you restart Matlab.